# Of Balls in Bins in Different Sections with Caps

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinations

> **Problem:**
>
> There are $19$ bins: $7, 5, 7$ in the left, centre and right sections respectively.
>   There are $8$ balls, some or all of which are to be put into these bins with the following conditions:
>   (1) A bin can only take $1$ ball.
>   (2) There can be at most $4$ balls in the left section. Similarly for the right section.
>   (3) Not all of the balls have to be put in bins.
>
> How many different ways are there of doing this?

**My attempt:**

Let $i,j,r$ represent the number of balls in the left, right and centre sections respectively.

First we count the number of ways $i\;(\le 4)$ balls can be placed in the $7$ left bins.
Then we do the same for the $j\;(\le 4)$ balls for the right bins.
After doing this the number of leftover balls is $8-i-j$.
We then count the number of ways to place $r\;(\le 8-i-j)$ balls into the centre bins.

The number of combinations required is given by:
$$\sum_{i=0}^4 \binom 7i\sum_{j=0}^4\binom 7j\sum_{r=0}^{\min(5,8-i-j)}\binom 5r$$

> **Questions**:
>
> Is this approach and formula correct?
>   If so, is there an alternative approach giving a shorter formulation?
>   If not, then what is the correct approach and answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach and formula are correct, and I don't see an approach that yields a shorter formulation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and confirmation! (+1)